# Editar campo imput text para luego actualizarlo en otra pagina

Tags: javascript, php

Necesito editar la hora y fecha de mi landing Page, para después actualizarla en el navegador del cliente, lo mas posible en un modulo administrador. Actualmente tengo que ingresar directamente al archivo JS. y colocar la fecha en la cual finalizara el conteo regresivo LO CUAL NO ES PRACTICO.

Nota: La pagina del cliente no consulta una base de datos para la hora, la pagina del cliente solo ejecuta directamente el archivo de JS que contiene la variable de hora y fecha.

**Modulo ideal para administrador**

```js
const fecha = "Dec 29, 2022 24:00:00"

var countDownDate = new Date(fecha).getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " Dias | " + hours + " Horas | " +
        minutes + " Minutos | " + seconds + " Segundos | ";

    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Flash Promo finalizada";
    }

}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>User</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Modulo Administrador</h1>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <!-- Aquí tienes el textarea oculto con la fecha de finalización -->
    <label for="">Ingrese la fecha en la cual finaliza la promoción:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="fechaFinal" rows="3" placeholder="Digite" >
      Dec 29, 2022 24:00:00
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar fecha y hora</button>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

[**Link del proyecto**](https://https:oboticariocolombia.com/landing_flash/index.php)

Comment: Link del proyecto: https://oboticariocolombia.com/landing_flash/index.php

Comment: A ver si lo he entendido... ¿quieres actualizar la hora desde un módulo de administración y que automáticamente se actualice en la página del cliente que actualmente ya tiene cargada en su navegador?

Comment: Si es así solo se me ocurre que lo hagas con Ajax y un timer (settimeout o setinterval) que vaya ejecutando la consulta de tanto en tanto, y en caso de cambio de hora se la actualice. También se podría hacer con websockets, pero de eso yo ni idea.  Prueba lo del ajax primero y actualiza tu pregunta con lo que hayas probado si es que te da algun tipo de error, gracias.

Comment: @masterguru Me parece que es otra cosa. Creo que quiere "const fecha" sea una variable a ingresar desde un módulo de administración, porque cada vez que tienen que cambiar el conteo regresivo tienen que editar el js a mano. Y al parecer sin usar base de datos. A mí lo que se me ocurre, es que genere el archivo js por medio de php cada vez que cambia la fecha

Comment: @Yussef si, también podría ser eso perfectamente. Si fuera eso entonces ojo con la cache del navegador, deberia agregar una coletilla al `main.js` en plan `main.js?1231233` en cada cambio que haga para forzar su recarga, sino tendrá problemas de cache en los navegadores de los clientes.